# How to deploy contract in Mist Browser connected to Ganache?

Tags: private-blockchain, mist, ganache

I connected Mist to my Private Ganache Blockchain, but when I try to deploy it it gives the following error:

**Returned Error: Method personal sign_Transaction not supported**

I can deploy contracts just fine using Ganache with Remix and EtherAtom. Mist seems to be the only one where this issue arises.